# Regex to capitalize words

Tags: regex, uppercase, lookbehind, bibtex, bibliography

I'm using a text editor to capitalize the titles of papers in a references file.

I have a similar structure

```
...
Title = {Direct synthesis of antimicrobial coatings based on tailored bi-elemental nanoparticles},
journal={APL Mat.},
...
```

and I want to capitalize only the words in the title section so that it becomes

```
...
Title = {Direct Synthesis of Antimicrobial Coatings Based on Tailored Bi-Elemental Nanoparticles},
journal={APL Mat.},
...
```

I tried using the lookbehing regex to search for **each** word followed by the word "Title" in the following way

```
(?<=Title)(\b.+?\b)
```

and I want to substitute it with

```
\u\1
```

for each occurrence in the text. 
However my code only selects the character after the "e" of *Title* and the "D" of *Direct*, and **cannot find the other occurrences** after that.

Can you help me? Thank you.

Comment: Try `(\G(?!^)(?:[^}\w]+(?:o[fn]|in))*[^}\w]+|Title\s*=\s*\{)(\w+)` to replace with `$1\u$2`. You may  add more exclusions into `(?:o[fn]|in)` group.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It worked, but exceptions always cause its failure.I tried fixing it by myself but I'm new to regex but I actually can't find out how to work with them.
I substituted it with $1\{\u$2\} so that it won't change the capitals letters anymore.
The main problems happens when I find other curly bracket already existing in the line like in the case "handbook of {XPS}: foo foo foo"
I tried to change it in #(\G(?!^)(?:[^}\w]+(?:o[fn]|in))*[^}\w]+|Title\s*=\s*\{)(\{?\w+\}?)# but then the problem is when i find two }}.

Thank you again!

Comment: I surprised myself by finding the following solution
(\G(?!^)(?:[^}\n\w]+(?:o[fn]|in))*[^}\n\w]+|Title\s*=\s*\{)(\{*\w+\}*)
the problem of using * instead of ? was that for some reason it was starting to select the newline as the word to change (can you explain me why? \}* should be only the closed braket from 0 to n times..), so I added the \n in the square brakets for the void space selection. My first day with regex is less frustrating than what i though. Thanks to you! :) (how can you embed code in the short answer?)

Comment: Ok, I see, the line breaks were matched, I just did not have longer text to test. So, `(\G(?!^)(?:[^}\n\w]+(?:o[fn]|in))*[^}\n\w]+|Title\s*=\s*\{)(\w+)` works, right?

Comment: (\G(?!^)(?:[^}\n\w]+(?:o[fn]|in|the|by|for|to|and*|a))*[^}\n\w]+|Title\s*=\s*\{)(\{*\w+\}*)
(note the last part to avoid the multiple parenthesis break)
worked. Thank you master!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
(\G(?!^)(?:[^}\n\w]+(?:o[fn]|in|the|by|for|to|and*|a))*[^}\n\w]+|Title\s*=\s*\{)(\w+)
```

and replace with `$1\u$2`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HHllOv/1) (it is slightly modified since regex101 does not seem to support `\u` operator).

**Details**

- `(\G(?!^)(?:[^}\n\w]+(?:o[fn]|in))*[^}\n\w]+|Title\s*=\s*\{)` - either of the two alternatives:

  - `\G(?!^)(?:[^}\n\w]+(?:o[fn]|in|the|by|for|to|and*|a))*[^}\n\w]+`:
  - `\G(?!^)` - the end of the previous match
  - `(?:[^}\n\w]+(?:o[fn]|in))*` - 0 or more repetitions of

    - `[^}\n\w]+` - 1 or more chars other than `}`, LF and a word char
    - `(?:o[fn]|in|the|by|for|to|and*|a)` - `of`, `on` or `in`, etc. (**add more words that should be excluded from capitalization here**)
  - `[^}\n\w]+` - 1 or more chars other than `}`, LF and a word char
  - `|` - or
  - `Title\s*=\s*\{` - `Title`, `=` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces and a `{`
- `(\w+)` - Group 2: one or more word chars.

Comment: It won't make much difference but didn't you mean `and?` instead of `and*`?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed I copied that part from OP. This part can/must be edited further to include those functional words that should stay in lowercase.